# How to return dictionary with minimum value at element(0)

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

In the example below, how do I return the dictionary item having the minimum value at element(0)? (I have modified the declaration)

```
 Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictSource2 = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
    {
    { 1, new List<string> { "5", "Programmers" }},
    { 2, new List<string> { "12", "Testers" }},
    { 3, new List<string> { "2", "Designers" }},
    };
```

I want to return the following data from the above dictionary-

```
2, "Designers"
```

I have written below:

```
string sminValue= dictSource2.Min(pair => pair.Value.ElementAt(0));
```

My solution works fine when value at ElementAt(0) has zero records, i.e. "Designers" has zero records, But otherwise it fails. Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: `new List<Employee> { 5, "Programmers" }` how does that even compile?

Comment: @leppie: one example: `using Employee = System.Object;` ;) (this is why dynamic typing is **such** an *good idea*)

Comment: @leppie, have just modified the declaration. Kindly advise

Comment: You know that 12 < 2 when comparing strings?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I have modified as below, and it works now-  var minValue = dictSource.Min(pair => Convert.ToInt32(pair.Value.ElementAt(0)));    Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @HimBromBeere, I have modified my code as below:

var minValue = dictSource.Min(pair => Convert.ToInt32(pair.Value.ElementAt(0)));

And it works now.

Ideally , I should have opted for a List of customtype instead of going for List of Strings.